# Helper methods in TT generators

Tags: c#, code-generation, t4

I am trying to put a helper method inside my T4 generator to make some of the generation logic a bit simpler, but I cant get it to compile correctly. I want to use this helper later in the .tt (not have it generated as output)

If I put the following

```
<#
    public static void Test()
    {
    }
#>
```

or

```
<#
    public static class Helpers 
    {
        public static void Test()
        {
        }
    }
#>
```

In my .tt i get the following error

> Compiling transform: } expected

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @TMcKeown: Look at the tags.  Specifically the last one.

Comment: @TMcKeown its a t4 template, its a way of generation code from code

Comment: ok, are you forgetting the namespace?

Comment: @TMcKeown i dont think so, something like this would work fine `<#
 string s = "abcd";
#>`

Comment: Try putting the second block inside `<#+ #>` (notice `+`)

Comment: @Pawel works perfectly, much appreciated, what exactly does the + signify?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Didn't see this comment, I commented on Pawel's answer to explain the difference between <# #> and <#+ #>.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try putting the second block inside `<#+ #>` (notice `+`)

Comment: To give some more detail on this: you can change the generator to be preprocessed (explained for example here: http://www.olegsych.com/2009/09/t4-preprocessed-text-templates/). The <# #> notation is generating code within main "TransformText()" call, where as the <#+ #> notation is generating code to class-scope, where you can introduce class members/methods.